# Fix build path error in searchable configuration xml file

Tags: android, xml, searchview

I'm trying to add searchview to my android application using android studio but when I first add the searchable.xml configuration file I get this error

`the fallowing classes could not be found: -searchable (fix build path,edit xml) and layout missing attributes`

When I build the project I get this errors :
`-no resource found that matches the given name(at 'resource' with value @searchable.xml)
-execution failed for task ':app.processDebugProcess'`

Any help??

```
enter code here<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:label="@string/search_label"
android:hint="@string/hint_search"
 />
```

Comment: <string name="search_label">labelname</string>

<string name="hint_search">hinttext</string>
keep inside string.xml file

Comment: already written there on sting.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **searchable.xml** file should be on **res/xml** folder and should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/hint_search"
    android:label="@string/search_label" >
</searchable>
```

Comment: You need to create it manually. Android does not create it by default.

Comment: theres only layout folder where all xml interfaces are located

Comment: Yes, in res folder there are many others like drawable, layout, menu, values, etc. You need to create a new folder called xml inside that res folder.

Comment: I assume you're using Android Studio. Right click on res folder. Select New and then Directory. In the Dialog that appears introduce the name of the folder you want to create. In this case, **xml**. And you're done. Now you need to put the searchable.xml file inside that folder.